# Who wins this and why? A5 or AJ?

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules

[image: hand]

Who wins this one, the person with A and 5 or the one with A and J? Could you please explain why?

Comment: Come on post the actual board.  Not just some picture.

Answer (score 1):

A♥ J♣ has a best 5 card hand of A♥ A⋄ 6⋄ 6♣ J♣ (Two pair, Aces and Sixes, Jack kicker)

A♠ 5♠ has a best 5 card hand of A♠ A⋄ 6⋄ 6♣ 7⋄ (Two pair, Aces and Sixes, Seven kicker)

Therefore, A♥ J♣ wins.

Comment: The cards are laid out weird in the picture two.. why is the 5 paired with the board when the 6 counterfeits it, I wonder.

Comment: Probably because it hasn't been understood that the A5 has been counterfeited and this is where the argument about which hand wins has stemmed from.